# Shapely's object.project method dealing with overlapping polyline

Tags: postgis, linear-referencing, shapely

So I am interested in knowing how far along a polyline a given point sits. Python's shapely package has a method to do such a thing, see the below code:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

ip = LineString([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]).interpolate(1.5)

print LineString([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]).project(ip)
> 1.5
```

Now if I changed the polyline to fold back on itself it only returns 1 distance (the smallest distance), see the code below:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString

ip = LineString([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]).interpolate(1.5)

print LineString([(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]).project(ip)
> 0.5
```

In reality the answer to this question is 0.5 and 1.5.

My question is how do I get it to return all of the distances that may belong to the single given point?

**UPDATE**

I found that the shapely module uses PostGIS commands, specifically for the object.project method it uses the ST_InterpolatePoint command.